# How to run dynamic python scripts at runtime?

Tags: python, subprocess, pypy

I am trying to get two aspects worked out :

1. First how do I run python script stored in DB as a BLOB in sandbox mode (maybe using PyPy sandbox)?
2. Secondly how can I generate the script itself from the code template (the code template been saved as BLOB in DB) and serve it with the required data ?

Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [eval()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval). But beware of security holes!
2. Please post your tempate code.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but you can't pass a script to eval() function. Instead execfile() does but doesn't let you import. I have gone through this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037913/add-a-python-script-at-runtime) but here it fetches from an URL instead of a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile(source, filename, mode[, flags[, dont_inherit]])
```

Compile the source into a code or AST object. Code objects can be executed by an exec statement or evaluated by a call to eval(). source can either be a string or an AST object. Refer to the ast module documentation for information on how to work with AST objects.